# How to convert the below response to String?

Tags: json, flutter, dart

Here is my List of maps. But I want to convert these to string.

```
[{tid: 20210813, title: hello3, description: hello good evening every one, _id: 62ecc3f047ff077fe8d4549e}, {tid: 20210812, title: hello, description: hello good evening every one, _id: 62ecc3f047ff077fe8d4549d}, {tid: 20210814, title: hello4, description: hello good evening every one, _id: 62ecc3f047ff077fe8d4549f}, {tid: 20210812, title: hello, description: hello good evening every one, _id: 62ecc3f047ff077fe8d454a0}, {tid: 20210812, title: hello, description: hello good evening every one, _id: 62ece09647ff077fe8d454e6}, {tid: 20210812, title: hello, description: hello good evening every one, _id: 62ece09647ff077fe8d454e9}, {tid: 20210813, title: 2766767236, description: hello good evening every one, _id: 62ece09647ff077fe8d454e7}, {tid: 20210814, title: hello4, description: hello good evening every one, _id: 62ece09647ff077fe8d454e8}]
```

Comment: It is already in string , you need a model class, also it is not formatted correctly

Comment: Could you write what your expected output is?

Comment: getAllTodos(BuildContext context) async {
    try {
      var todos = await _homeRepo.getAllTodos(context);
     
      return todoFromJson(todos.toString());
    } catch (e) {
      Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: e.toString());
      return null;
    }
  }  // I will that response in todos and I want to pass that response in todoFromJson which accepts string

Answer (score 0):

You can use this model class

```dart
import 'dart:convert';

class ModelClass {
  final int? tid;
  final String? title;
  final String? description;
  final String? sId;
  ModelClass({
    this.tid,
    this.title,
    this.description,
    this.sId,
  });

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    final result = <String, dynamic>{};

    if (tid != null) {
      result.addAll({'tid': tid});
    }
    if (title != null) {
      result.addAll({'title': title});
    }
    if (description != null) {
      result.addAll({'description': description});
    }
    if (sId != null) {
      result.addAll({'sId': sId});
    }

    return result;
  }

  factory ModelClass.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    return ModelClass(
      tid: map['tid']?.toInt(),
      title: map['title'],
      description: map['description'],
      sId: map['sId'],
    );
  }

  String toJson() => json.encode(toMap());

  factory ModelClass.fromJson(String source) =>
      ModelClass.fromMap(json.decode(source));
}
```

And to get items

```dart
  final data = jsonDecode(response.body) as List;
      return data.map((e) => ModelClass.fromMap(e)).toList();
```

Comment: Can anyone say how to add shimmer effect for the below code                            CircleAvatar(
                        backgroundImage: (_image != null)
                            ? FileImage(_image)
                            : (_userImage != null && _userImage != "")
                                ? NetworkImage(_userImage)
                                : NetworkImage(
                                    'https://i.pinimg.com/550x/03/db/57/03db57bc63f03f52c0897a4cf99f23d2.jpg'),
                        radius: 75,
                      ),

Comment: when image will be null?  try replacing fixed widget, might be `NetworkImage( 'i.pinimg.com/550x/03/db/57/…),`

Answer (score 0):

You need to decode the response into json before getting values

```
getAllTodos(BuildContext context) async { 
 try { 
   var todos = await _homeRepo.getAllTodos(context); 
   return todoFromJson(jsonDecode(todos)); 
 }
 catch (e) { 
   Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: e.toString()); return null;
 } 
}
```

Comment: import 'dart:convert';
Todo todoFromJson(String str) => Todo.fromJson(json.decode(str));
String todoToJson(Todo data) => json.encode(data.toJson());
List<Todo> todosFromJson(String str) => List<Todo>.from(json.decode(str).map((x) => Todo.fromJson(x)));
String todosToJson(List<Todo> data) => json.encode(List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())));
class Todo {
    Todo({
        this.id,
        this.tid,
        this.title,
        this.description,
        this.isSynced,
    });
    int id;
    String tid;
    String title;
    String description;
    int isSynced;

Comment: factory Todo.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Todo(
        id: json["id"],
        tid: json["tid"],
        title: json["title"],
        description: json["description"],
        isSynced: json["isSynced"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "id": id,
        "tid": tid,
        "title": title,
        "description": description,
        "isSynced": isSynced,
    };
}

Comment: The above one is my model class

Comment: Go on https://javiercbk.github.io/json_to_dart/

Comment: You can convert your response to model class and then after you can convert response into model class

Answer (score 0):

You didn't phrase your question very clearly, but here's some speculation.

First, the map itself has the wrong structure. This is what the correct one looks like:

```dart
List myList = [
  {
    'tid': 20210813,
    'title': 'hello3',
    'description': 'hello good evening every one',
    '_id': '62ecc3f047ff077fe8d4549e'
  },
  {}
];
```

You can convert everything to a string with a simple command toString(). Do a for and call toString().

```dart
main() {
  String str = myList.toString(); // or all
  
  for (final m in myList ){
    m.toString();
  }
}
```

However, I assume that in your case you need to convert the maps into a model class by presenting a toJson()/fromJson() or toString()/fromString() method for conversions.